# Fetching data with redux-thunk middle ware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am learning react-redux async actions with redux-thunk, I would like to fetch data from API (my local database), Unfortunately fetching data with redux-thunk middleware data is not fetched but without thunk middleware data is fetched.

So here are action creators with thunk middleware, **which is not working**

```
// retriev comments
export const fetchComments= () =>{
  return dispatch =>{
    dispatch(fetchCommentsRequest);
    axios.get('/api/v1/todo')
    .then(response =>{
      const comments =response.data;
      dispatch(fetchCommentsSucces(comments))
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      const erroMsg =errors.messages
      dispatch(fetchCommentsFailure(error))
    })
  }
}
```

And here is console log result :

[image]

Here is a component where I am calling the function to fetch data from API,

```
import React, {useEffect}from 'react'
import { fetchComments} from '../store/actions'
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function Dashboard(userComments) {

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchComments();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
        <p>Fetching data</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("I am state", state);
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.Auth.isAuthenticated,
    user: state.Auth.user,
    userComments: state.comments
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchComments: () => dispatch(fetchComments()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

The whole store can be found here: [store](https://github.com/throne1986/twitter-app/tree/master/resources/js/store)

Can someone tells me why data is not fetched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your thunk, dispatch the action properly i.e. call the `fetchCommentsRequest` function (you are providing reference)

```js
export const fetchComments= () =>{
  return dispatch =>{
    dispatch(fetchCommentsRequest()); //<-----call the fuction
    axios.get('/api/v1/todo')
    .then(response =>{
      const comments =response.data;
      dispatch(fetchCommentsSucces(comments))
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      const erroMsg =errors.messages
      dispatch(fetchCommentsFailure(error))
    })
  }
}
```

2. In your repo, the `fetchCommentsSucces` needs to take an argument.

```js
export function fetchCommentsSucces(comments){ //<----pass argument i.e comments
  console.log('success')
  return{
    type: ActionTypes.FETCH_COMMENTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: comments //<----provide correct payload  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with how `fetchComments` method is called inside the `<Dashboard>` component.

Once a React component is connected to a Redux store, the data from the store (`mapStateToProps`) and the functions it can use to dispatch actions to the store (`mapDispatchToProps`) are passed to that component as an object.

The `<Dashboard>` component receives this `props` object that can be accessed inside it like:

```
function Dashboard(props) {

  useEffect(() =>{
    props.fetchComments();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
        <p>Fetching data</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

or using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
function Dashboard({ isAuthenticated, user, userComments, fetchComments }) {

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchComments();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
        <p>Fetching data</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```